# There has to be an article before singular countable nouns, right?

Tags: articles

I've gone through [the tutorial about "A/an and the" from English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the) in which I guess I understand the rules.

Regarding singular countable nouns, the tutorial states

> We only use a/an with singular countable nouns

> We can use the with singular and plural countable nouns

The tutorial does explicitly claims something like

> there has to be an article before singular countable nouns.

However, in practice, the statement seems to appear to be a rule.  Is my understanding correct?

---

This is the precise version, which is waiting to be reviewed.

"**Usually, there has to be a determiner before singular countable nouns that are not proper nouns**"

Comment: There doesn't have to only be an article. There could be a possessive pronoun, for instance, or an adjective. But there does have to be *something* in front of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do only use "a" before singular countable nouns.  The word "a" means "one" and so it implies the noun is countable and singular.

> a cat

There could be other types of determiner:

> my cat
> which cat?
> that cat

and so on.

If you are willing to accept proper nouns as "singular and countable", they often can be used without any determiner.

> John

or words like "winter", "school"

You can argue that these are not "singular countable nouns".

Comment: You answer makes my statement complete. Thank you. To eliminate the ambiguity, is it correct to say "**there has to be a determiner before singular countable nouns that are not proper nouns**" ?

Comment: What would you say about "go to school"  is school "uncountable"? But yes in general singular uncountable nouns do need at determiner, and if undetermined, then you use the article "a".

Comment: @JamesK, is there any rule that we have always to use an article beforea word that is singular, countable, and common noun. I have a question with a word, paracetamol. We do not use any article before paracetamol which is a singular, countable, and common noun. Why ?

Comment: Because "paracetamol" is not countable - or rather it has both countable and non-countable senses.  "A paracetamol" means "a pill containing paracetamol" but as a substance it is non-count